# using LinkPad 5 I am unable to load a EF6 custom dll and using entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linqpad

I have attempted to access an existing custom `DbContext` from my solution, using `LinqPad 5`, and use that test\develop queries and code.  (I had achieved the same 2 years ago in a similar project)

I am able to create the connection, and it tests successfully but when I try to access it in a query  I consistently receive the following error.

> configuration system failed to initialize
>   inner exception: SerializationException
>                     Type 'EMTPassportDomain.Supermodel.Persistance.EMTPassportDbContext' in assembly 'EMTPassportDomain, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked as serializable

Due to our use of an in house framework I have to set several things up but this is what a query looks like (at least based on my earlier successful attempt with a similar project)

```
void Main()
{
    var serializerSettings = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings;

    var contractResolver = (DefaultContractResolver)serializerSettings.ContractResolver;
    contractResolver.IgnoreSerializableAttribute = true;

    SupermodelInitialization.Init<EMTPassportDbContext>(new CustomRepoFactory(), webApiAuthFilter: new EMTPassportBasicHttpAuthenticateAttribue());
//    InitializerManager.InitPerConfig(new List<IDatabaseInitializer<EMTPassportDbContext>>
//    {
//        new EMTPassportCreateDatabaseIfNotExists(),
//        new EMTPassportDropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges(),
//        new EMTPassportDropCreateDatabaseAlways()
//    });

    using (new EMTPassportUnitOfWork(ReadOnly.Yes))  //EMTPassportUnitOfWorkIfNoAmbientContext
    {
        var userRepo = (EMTUserRepo)RepoFactory.Create<EMTUser>();
        var test = userRepo.Items;//.Where(u => u.GovEmail == GovEmail && u.Id != Id);
        test.Take(1).ToList().Dump();
    };
}
```

I've included most names spaces, copied the `dll.config` file over into `LinqPad.query.config`  I'm just not sure how to proceed....

I did get this working a couple of years ago after some futsing but I just don't know how to move forward and I miss my `LinqPad`.

Sorry if this isn't clear, this is my first stackoverflow question ever...
and thanks in advance.

Comment: I assume that this has to do with serializing entities as proxy objects (that have a reference to the context they were created by). Could you try to disable proxy creation?

Comment: ok I will give that a try. Thank you for responding!